# When using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with tomcat should I use S3 for all my static content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently I deploy my application war file to EB and it contains the code for generating pages plus any png's needed for rendering the pages, I was happy with this because all in one place.

But now I know you can configure a S3 bucket as a website would it cheaper for me and faster for the user to store all those images in an S3bucket configured as a website and to code the full S3 path into my code  tags.

But it makes deployment more complex because now only part of the deployment is handled in the tomcat.war. Also putting images into a new location is one thing, but if I had static pages that would start affecting the urls

i.e if page1 was deployed with tomcat and page 2 was a static page the urls would have to be something like

- http://widget.com/page1.jsp
- http://static.widget.com/page2.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you are using cloudfront, in that case, all static files which can be cached are already cached on cloudfront (dynamic requests as well by the way, if they have the same url and don't specify no caching), I don't see what benefit you would get from taking static files and putting them on S3.  On the contrary, you would have longer down time on upgrades, as you would need to update both the java and the s3 files to keep your service consistent, or have some complex deployment mechanism which versions every commit.

Unless you have terabytes of static images served by your service (which would be quite a problem to deploy anyhow), the costs of keeping the files on the service disks vs. putting them on S3 are negligible.

Comment: what I am seeing is that although I have Cloudfront configued for best perfomance it doesnt always serve the files, now I understand that the first time a request is based from edge location you'll get a miss , but I still seem to be getting misses after a couple,of weeks. I was concerned that I had filled my Cloudfront cache but I dont know if this is possible, if this concern is unwarranted I think I agree with what youve said.

Comment: I think the issue is just that Cloudfront has 60 edge locations, I thought there was just one for Europe, one for US .. but there ar emany more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your questions.

I think it's a good idea to move to S3. It is cheap, reliable, and fast.
More over you can use amazon cloudfront so your content will be deliver everywhere in the world **very fast**.

Comment: okay Ill rephrase, the majority of my website is generated dynamically and hence cannot be hosted on S3, but should I split the non dynamic content (mostly images so it is on S3). I do always use Cloudfront in front of my server but still some image requests do not get handled by cloudfront and come down to my server.